# Populate VBA combobox with MySQL table names

Tags: mysql, vba, combobox

I am trying to populate a combobox in a Userform in VBA with the table names of a specific database in SQL.

I have tried 2 queries: the "show tables"
and the "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'DBname' ORDER BY table_name;"
but both return a value for the RecordCount of -1.

Here's the general code I use, with rst being the recordset:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
Dim strMysql As String


Application.Run "Connect_to_SQL_DB.ConnectToDB"

strMysql = "SHOW TABLES"
rst.Open strMysql, conn

MsgBox rst.RecordCount
me.cboComboBox.List = rst.GetRows

End Sub
```

Is there a different way that I should use to feed the table names to the combobox? As far as I understand the queries I am using still return arrays, which should be compatible to fill the list.

Edit: RecordCount issue has been fixed, so I could try with a For loop with the `.Additem` command, but I get a runtime error 91.
Without the For loop with the `combobox.List = rst.GetRows` I still only get the first item.

Comment: Does the information_schema return if you take out the schema name?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, I am to delete the "WHERE table_schema = 'DBname'" part. In this case it does return the query, but it also lists the tables from a second DB, which I do not want to include in the combobox.

Comment: "both return a value for the RecordCount of -1" - `RecordCount` is often unreliable unless you've first performed a `MoveLast` to go to the last record.  Better to test for `rst.EOF`

Comment: rst.EOF gives a False result for both queries, and so does rst.BOF

Comment: I am able to query separate elements with the `LIMIT n-1, 1` addition, but then I'd still like to have the upper bound for the FOR loop be defined by the `RecordCount` or something equivalent, which would be up to date with changes in the database. With this approach I'd want to use the `combobox.AddItem` in the loop to populate it with each element one by one.

Comment: So I managed to get a correct `RecordCount` with the addition of `rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient` before opening the recordset. However the `Me.cboComboBox.Additem rst.Getrows` in my loop returns the Object variable not defined error.

Comment: I started using watches on some expressions and stepping through the code. I've noticed the rst.GetRows after I open my recordset with the query updates to Type = Variant/Variant (0 to 0, 0 to 114) as there are 115 elements in the query. I can expand the expression, and I see each value that I'd like to fill into the list of the combobox besides a rst.GetRows(0,i) with i going from 0 to 114. If I want to use the cbo.List = rst.GetRows to fill it I get  runtime error 3021, but both EOF and BOF are false.

Comment: Following my previous comment, if I want to use a for loop with combobox.Additem rst(i).Value then once the code is on the For i = 1 to rst.Recordcount the values are reported properly, but after it jumps into the for loop the values say "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal" for rst(i)